# ERROR: relation "music_pionizex_id_seq" does not exist SQL state: 42P01

Tags: python, postgresql

I am not able to reset the ID values to restart with 1 instead of the numbers they are currently indexed at.

I have tried to use the code mentioned in other answers but my table name already has an underscore i.e. "_", so I think its becoming a problem here with the sequence.

```
ALTER SEQUENCE "music_pionizex_id_seq" RESTART WITH 1;

ERROR:  relation "music_pionizex_id_seq" does not exist
SQL state: 42P01
```

Comment: Run `\ds` in `psql` and see if your sequence shows up. If it is in a schema not on the `search_path`, run `\ds schemaname.*`. This will show you how the sequence is called.

Answer (score 1):

You can fetch the sequence name from the table/column using [`pg_get_serial_sequence`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html)

```sql
SELECT pg_get_serial_sequence('myschema.mytable','mycolumn');
```

You can then embed this name and reset the sequence to 1:

```
SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('myschema.mytable','mycolumn'), 1,false);
```